# Removing the last blank line in Tkinter entry

Tags: python, regex, tkinter

python version 3.9.2

> What the script does and what creates problem

The script below replaces '\n' with '-o -name' to separate each items.

Input will always be in this format(copied from excel)

```
A.java  
B.java  
C.java
```

Note that it will always have blank lines since copy&paste creates it

desired output:

```
A.class -o -name B.class -o -name C.class
```

but the blank line from the input creates the problem.

script's output :

```
A.class -o -name B.class -o -name C.class -o -name
```

> In short, I want every '\n' **but the last line** to be replaced with ' -o -name '

source :

```
from tkinter import *
import re

win = Tk()
win.title("Find command for evidence doc")
win.resizable(0,0)


#Converting
def replace():

    # removing blank line <- THIS needs to be improved
    original = entry.get("1.0",'end')
    original = re.sub(r'\n\s*\n','\n',original,re.MULTILINE)
    print(original)
    
    # Replace .java to .class
    javaToClass = re.compile(re.escape('.java'), re.IGNORECASE)
    converted = \
    "find . \( -name " + javaToClass.sub('.class',original).replace("\n", " -o -name ") + "\) -exec ls -gG --color {} \; | grep '[^/]*$'i"

    # Copy to clipboard
    clip = Tk()
    clip.withdraw()
    clip.clipboard_clear()
    clip.clipboard_append(converted)
    clip.destroy()

    # output
    output.delete("1.0",'end')
    output.insert(END, str(converted))

# Componants
l1 = Label(win, text="Enter text:")
entry = Text(win, width=70, height=15, wrap=WORD)
button = Button(win, text="Convert", width=20)
l2 = Label(win, text="Converted text: (auto copied to clipboard)")
output = Text(win, width=70, height=15, wrap=WORD)


l1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, sticky=W)
entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=(0,10))
button.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=5)
l2.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, sticky=W)
output.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=(0,10))

button.configure(command=replace)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: If your string ends with `'\n'`, just use `.strip()` to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your pattern to detect all `\n` that are followed by a letter.

Then replace the matched `\n` to `-o -name`  and use `strip()` to remove the final `\n`

```
string = '''A.java  
B.java  
C.java  
  '''

pattern = r'\n(?=[a-zA-Z])'
replace = '-o -name '
re.sub(pattern, replace, string).strip()

#'A.java  -o -name B.java  -o -name C.java'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it could be done with re but there is a simple python way, if the input will always be in that format

if you could just get the file names in a list and the add ".class -o -name" at thend and join them it would solve the problem

How about joining each element with and  ".class -o -name" that way the last one wont be there.

```
finished = " -o -name ".join(i.replace(".jave",".class") for i in orignal.split())
```